# AWS Proton parameters - clarify how the schema.yaml parameters are consumed in CF template

Tags: amazon-web-services, schema, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

After going through the docs and examples I haven't clarified where exactly the parameters from the schema.yaml file are used.

Using the AWS code example here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-proton-sample-templates/blob/main/lambda-crud-svc/service/schema/schema.yaml

Pertinent section of the schema.yaml file:

```
schema:
  format:
    openapi: "3.0.0"
  service_input_type: "CrudServiceInput"
  pipeline_input_type: "PipelineInputs"

  types:
    CrudServiceInput:
      type: object
      description: "Input properties for a Lambda backed CRUD API. When given a resource name, this input will be used to generate Create, Read, Update and Delete API methods and lambdas."
      properties:
        resource_name:
          type: string
          description: "The resource to generate a CRUD API for"
          minLength: 1
          maxLength: 50
          default: "greeting"
        resource_handler:
          type: string
          description: "The handler path to find the CRUD methods for this API"
          minLength: 1
          maxLength: 50
          default: "index"
        lambda_memory:
          type: number
          description: "The size of your Lambda functions in MB"
          default: 512
          minimum: 1
          maximum: 3008
...
```

I would expect that in the cloudformation.yaml file I would be able to reference `{{service_input_type.resource_name}}`, but it is referred to as `{{service.resource_name}}`.

Assume that Proton somehow has *service* namespace mapped to the values in *service_input_type*.
HOWEVER

When you use that logic for "lambda_memory" parameter in the same `service_input_type` object, it doesn't work, because in the template file it refers to this as `service_instance.lambda_memory`

Can anyone clarify the following:

1. How are the schema.yaml parameters consumed in the
   cloudformation.yaml template?
2. Further... how do the "xx-spec.yaml"
   files play into the mix. I assume they are merged into the service
   template when creating the instance, but the parameter naming
   convention is also different than the template parameters above.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `service_instance` as the namespace, with the exception of

1. if you are parametrizing a pipeline template, where you can use `service`;
2. if you are referring to the name, where you can use the `service_name` and `service_instance_name` variables (no namespace).

A Proton service is ultimately a collection of service instances with a pipeline. When Proton provisions infrastructure, it will create a CloudFormation stack for every instance, so the parameters are always applied at the instance level. The pipeline is an exception because it doesn't belong to a single environment, and so in certain cases, you might need to refer to the service as a whole.

As per the `xx-spec.yaml` files - Those are actually the reflections of the parameters that the developer might provide. If you use the Proton UX to create a new service, Proton will output a file like that and store it to reflect the parameters for that particular service.